# Не могу вызвать глобальную функцию в теле класса

Tags: php

Есть некая условная функция:

```
function environment() {
  return 'developer';
}
```

И есть некий условный класс, в котором объявляется переменная:

```
сlass SomeClass {
  private $filename = "/var/www/" . environment() . "/engine/debugger.log";
}
```

Но почему-то при выполнении кода происходит ошибка:

> Constant expression contains invalid operations

Почему я не могу вызывать глобальную функцию в теле класса и как мне достичь желаемого результата?

Answer (score 1):

Ну, вроде бы подобные действия выполняются в конструкторе класса

```
function environment() {
    return 'developer';
}

class SomeClass {
    private $filename;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->filename = "/var/www/" . environment() . "/engine/debugger.log";
    }
}

$obj = new SomeClass;

var_dump($obj);
```